# DISTINCT isn't removing dupes

Tags: t-sql

I am not sure how to use DISTINCT in an AB BA fashion. For instance, I have two columns BoughtLoyaltyProgramId, SoldLoyaltyProgramId. But even when I use DISTINCT, it produces a duplicate when the same code in a boughtloyaltyprogramid appears in soldloyaltyprogramid. I want no dupes but I have no idea how this works with multiple columns and pairings.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC AA
    @LPPProgramID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
    @DateFrom DATETIME ,
    @DateTo DATETIME
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT TOP ( 5 )
        BoughtLoyaltyProgramId ,
        SoldLoyaltyProgramId ,
        DateTransactionCleared ,
        ExchangeRate
FROM    dbo.PEX_ClearedTransactions
WHERE   DateTransactionCleared >= @DateFrom
        AND DateTransactionCleared < @DateTo
        AND ( BoughtLoyaltyProgramId = @LPPProgramID
              OR SoldLoyaltyProgramId = @LPPProgramID
            )
ORDER BY ExchangeRate;

GO
```

Comment: Distinct applies to all columns that you query, not just the first 2. Does it still contain duplicates if you consider all selected columns?

Comment: Can you show results of the query? I don't quite understand what's going on.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Show us some example data to help.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is per ROW, so the value in the columns in a row are in a distinct combination, the data isn't compared in each column of a row, to other columns in that row.

You likely will also want to do some comparison in your Where statement for the column data.

Comment: 1. It contains duplicates if you consider all columns. The results of the query show a bunch of Bought userids, Solduserids, exchange data, all that stuff. I can get the exact results if you want. I guess you guys said it best, DISTINCT is per row, not per column and I want to have no dupes throughout all the columns but I'm not skilled enough with TSQL yet to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get all distinct values from two columns:

```
SELECT distinct * from
(SELECT BoughtLoyaltyProgramId
FROM dbo.PEX_ClearedTransactions
UNION ALL 
SELECT SoldLoyaltyProgramId
FROM dbo.PEX_ClearedTransactions) as A
```

Comment: Dennis, I tried that yesterday and it didn't work. Still showed dupes.

Comment: Show what you mean by dupes, I am quite sure it won't show what I consider to be duplicates.

Comment: A specific userID in Bought shows up in Sold (because you can be both a buyer of airline points and a seller).

Comment: @user2689499 I think I understand now, see whether my edited answer can get you started.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, I will try this but can you help me with the syntax of the syntax of the entire stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT boughtloyaltyprogramid, 
                soldloyaltyprogramid, 
                datetransactioncleared, 
                exchangerate, 
                RN=Row_number() OVER( 
                    partition BY boughtloyaltyprogramid, soldloyaltyprogramid 
                    ORDER BY exchangerate) 
         FROM   dbo.pex_clearedtransactions 
         WHERE  datetransactioncleared >= @DateFrom 
                AND datetransactioncleared < @DateTo 
                AND ( boughtloyaltyprogramid = @LPPProgramID 
                       OR soldloyaltyprogramid = @LPPProgramID )) 
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM   cte 
WHERE  RN = 1 
ORDER  BY exchangerate
```

Comment: Tim is there no way to do it as a stored procedure? It has to be a CTE?

Comment: @user2689499: You can use a `CTE` in a stored-procedure without a problem. It's just like a sub-query.

Comment: Tim, I guess what I'm asking is for the entire syntax in the stored procedure. Where I would add that CTE, etc, if you could help me with that.

Comment: Can you help me out with the entire syntax? I'm pretty new to SQL(less than a year) so I have a lot of trouble.